# I get a 404 using the integrated server when POSTing to a php script

Tags: php, jquery, windows, http-status-code-404, phpstorm

```
<script>
    $.post("api.php", {action: 'check_login'}, function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'success') {
            $('#loginForm').hide();
            $('#loginHeader').text('You are already logged in.');
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('You will now be redirected.');
                $(window.location).attr("href", "http://example.com");
            }, 3000);
        }
    }, "JSON");
</script>
```

The above jQuery script POSTs this request to a php script in the same folder:

```
POST http://localhost:63342/100D100/api.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:63342/100D100/login.html?_ijt=taksdipisi3m6dq085nom202e2
Accept-Language: it-IT
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 18
Host: localhost:63342
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: Phpstorm-b9495478=581c317c-7b73-4419-92d8-ab238525aac4

action=check_login
```

It works on a normal server, but fails with a 404 when using PhpStorm's integrated server:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
content-type: text/html
content-length: 148
server: PhpStorm 2016.3.2
date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 14:19:21 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

<!doctype html><title>404 Not Found</title><h1 style="text-align: center">404 Not Found</h1><hr/><p style="text-align: center">PhpStorm 2016.3.2</p>
```

The file is definitely there. What can I try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check the permissions if the path is correct.

Comment: permissions seems fine

Comment: Try to overwrite the 404 error with `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');` in your file, first line of code.

Comment: Most likely it's an issue with built-in web server (especially with POST data or FILE uploads -- e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317) -- better user proper web server for this (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc). There are plenty of bundles with Apache for many OS (XAMPP is the most commonly mentioned)

Comment: @Ionut my php script does not output `<!doctype html><title>404 Not Found</title><h1 style="text-align: center">404 Not Found</h1><hr/><p style="text-align: center">PhpStorm 2016.3.2</p>`. Anyway I tried again overriding the status but nothing changed.

Comment: @LazyOne but having a built-in server with live edit capability is so convenient!

Comment: @beppe9000 I agree .. but if your situation is caused by misbehaving software that prevents your code from working... The only other thing I may suggest is to submit Support Ticket directly with devs/support team -- they will give you precise answer: misconfiguration from your end or a bug in their software: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new (and watch after ticket I have previously mentioned)

Comment: for now i'm going to setup some local server